# LWC - Retrieve element height value from js

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a long text that I'm truncating after 3 rows using the class: slds-line-clamp_small

I also have the need, when clicking on a "See more" text at the bottom of the text container, to show more rows. In this case I'm simply setting the element class to "".

```
seeMore() {
    if(this.descriptionClass == "slds-line-clamp_small") {
        this.descriptionlabel = "See less";
        this.descriptionClass = "";
    }
    else{
        this.descriptionlabel = "See more";
        this.descriptionClass = "slds-line-clamp_small";
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, apart from the fact that I'd like to have the "see more" text visible only in case it's needed.

I thought I could easily solve this using document.getelementbyid, but I can't.

So I'm thinking how can I access the style of the div from my JS and check the line height of the text (e.g. line-height is 20px, and I want to check if it's more than 3 rows, i check if the div height is greater than 20*3px).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you need to [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work) by using template.querySelector

Comment: and from there? how do I access the value for example? also that won't allow me to use ids, how do i know which div I'm selecting?

Comment: using class names? or any other selector? just not id's